# C++ Struct Array - Why does it have to be a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

It took me a while to figure out how to make an array of the data structure I had created. I eventually figured it has to be  a pointer, but why?

```
struct Food{
int weight;
double price;
string name;
};

Food *foods = new Food[5]; // Why a pointer?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `new[]` allocates a chunk of memory, and gives you a *pointer* to that memory. In the case of `new Food[5]` there will be space for five objects of type `Food`, each default constructed. The pointer you get is to the first `Food` object of the five.

You can also use

```
Food foods[5];
```

to create an array.

However, the preferred way to create "arrays" in C++ is to use either [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or if you need a dynamic array (or need it to be on the heap) [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::array<Food, 5> foods;  // Create a static fixed-size array of 5 Food objects

std::vector<Food> foods(5);  // Create a dynamic, expandable array of 5 Food object
```

Comment: you could mention std::array or why to use std::vector over new[]

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need it to be a pointer, you could easily create a global/local array:

```
Food foods[5];
```

When on heap, arrays can be of variadic length:

```
Food *foods = new Food[std::rand() + 1];
```

But you have to delete them as arrays explicitly:

```
delete[] foods; // otherwise they leak
```

Most of the time it makes sense to utilize STL's containers:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

std::vector<Food> foods(5, cheezeburger()); // in case we need more cheeseburgers
std::array<Food, 5> foods; // in case five cheeseburgers should be enough for everyone
```

They'll do all the annoying memory management for you.

STL's *automatic pointers* are also aware of arrays on the heap.